# Does the university matter in case of a job in Europe?

Tags: europe

If someone does a Ph.D. from a reputed university of an influential country like the USA, UK, Australia, France, and so on, does he get preference in most parts of Europe, or, do Europeans prefer the graduates from their native universities in case of teaching jobs?

Say, a Polish guy Mr. *X* gets a Ph.D. from the University of Minnesota in the USA and goes back to Poland, and another guy Mr. *Y* gets a Ph.D. from one of the top universities in Poland.

If **all other factors are equal**, who would get the preference in case of a teaching job? I mean, does the university matter here?

Comment: I can't speak specifically about teaching jobs Europe but I know in other industries, hiring managers tend to look favorably upon applicants from schools they're *familiar with*. Maybe they know someone who went there or they've had good luck with applicants from those schools in the past. And the chances of that being true tend to go up with geographic proximity.

Comment: Teaching pre-school or in a university?

Comment: @Kilisi, tertiary level institution.

Answer (score 1):

Teaching is in most (all?) countries a job where you're employed by the state. There are normally quite clear prerequisites and your university shouldn't matter much.

It's different if you mean university jobs or jobs in private education of course.

Comment: You can see have multiple qualified would-be teachers applying to the same opening though right? I presume that the interview board would consider the person's academic achievements as a factor in hiring or passing on a candidate.

Answer (score 1):

So long as it was a reputable university, the name or location of the university will not matter too much. I'd say that 2 PdDs are not equal based solely on the degree, Universities looking to hire a professor will be interested in:

**1. Your area of research**

Does it align with the University's interests? Does your research require extensive equipment or funding and can they supply that? Is this a field they wish to be prominent leaders in? Does your research align well with other researchers and professors at the university?

**2. Published works, papers, studies, etc.**

Are you well regarded by your peers?

**TLDR;**

Of course with the degree, research, papers, etc all being equal, the school of more prominent standing is normally a better decision (even University of Oxford hires in Professors from the United States and other countries). But you should focus which school to attend based on its alignment to your research and career interests. The advisor and staff you work with at the university will make or break a lot of your experience so go where you feel is the best environment for you to thrive.